# SWITCH formula help in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, spotfire

First post here.  My organisation for better or worse are trying to move things from Spotfire to Power BI and I'm exploring how easy/hard it will be to recreate some things in Power BI.

A typical sort of expression in our models looks like this:

*when ([BOOK] in ("AAAA", "BBBB")) and ([MKT1] in ("Curve1", "Curve2")) then "XXXXX" *

So if something is in *either *book AAAA or BBBB **AND **is against *either *CURVE1 or CURVE2 than it gets classified as XXXXX.

At my level of knowledge of DAX I would now have to write four lines of code to replace this one line: one for AAAA/Curve1, one for BBBB/Curve 1 etc.

Is there a simple way in DAX to replicate this ability to create a list of criterion?  Some of the lists run to 10+ items so it would be a massive help!

Thanks!

I've tried OR but this doesn't seem to get me there.  Googling has been no help - just multiple criteria, but with only one value per criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question but leaving active as maybe it'll help someone else.

It seems the "IN" function works just the same in PowerBI as it does in Spotfire, except for a few changes to Syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CROSSJOIN function to achieve this:

I hope You don't mind if I use DAX Studio:

```
EVALUATE
VAR BOOK = SELECTCOLUMNS({"AAAA","BBBB"},"BookName",[Value])
VAR MKT1 = SELECTCOLUMNS({"Curve 1","Curve 2"},"CurveName",[Value])
VAR FinalTable = CROSSJOIN(BOOK,MKT1)
RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS(
    FinalTable,
    "Composite",CONCATENATE([BookName] & "/",[CurveName])
    )
```

ResultSet:

[image: DAXStudio]

You can achieve the same in Power BI:

```
Result = 
VAR BOOK = SELECTCOLUMNS({"AAAA","BBBB"},"BookName",[Value])
VAR MKT1 = SELECTCOLUMNS({"Curve 1","Curve 2"},"CurveName",[Value])
VAR FinalTable = CROSSJOIN(BOOK,MKT1)
RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS(
    FinalTable,
    "Composite",CONCATENATE([BookName] & "/",[CurveName])
    )
```

ResultSet:
[image: PBI_NewTable]

Then you can use any columns of this table in a SWITCH() statement :)

Comment: Thank you for the response!  Will definitely look into this functionality - it's definitely above me for now :)